# Swift app: Flag a binary as "restricted" to the dynamic linker

Tags: swift, ios9, dylib

I am looking for a way to mark a binary as "restricted" while the code is written in swift.

In particular I am talking about setting these flags to the linker to prevent dynamic library loading:
`-Wl,-sectcreate,__RESTRICT,__restrict,/dev/null`

This works on devices >= iOS10 but not on iOS9 which crashes with:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/[...]
  Reason: image not found
```

I assume that there should be a way to "whitelist" the `libswiftCore.dylib` library.

Comment: I found the same thing on iOS9 device.  But my iOS9 device was Jailbroken and had Cycryipt installed, so it was trying to auto-inject dynamic libraries.  Was your ios 9 device clean?

Comment: Yes, it was NOT jailbroken.